# Shorten an if statement with lots of || operators

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to do an `if` so I don't have to do lots of `||` operations?

So is there anyway to shorten this to make it easier to read?

```
if(t.triggerOn == TriggerOn.CreationDelay || t.triggerOn == TriggerOn.CollisionDelay || t.triggerOn == TriggerOn.RigidbodyRestDelay || t.triggerOn == TriggerOn.LayerCollisionDelay || t.triggerOn == TriggerOn.EnterRadiusDelay){
    // Do something
}
```

`TriggerOn` is an `enum`

Comment: In a lot of cases, no.  Probably not in yours, either.  Personally, I would put a carriage return after each `||`, just to stack them vertically... I think it's easier to read.

Comment: Setting up flags on the `TriggerOn` enum would probably help you shorten it, but it will be less easy to read.

Comment: any way to shorten it would obscure the intent

Comment: if triggerOn is a flag enum then you could do: if ((t.triggerOn & (TriggerOn.CreationDelay | TriggerOn.CollisionDelay | ...) != 0) {...}

Comment: @pm100 mysql has an `in` feature, I was hoping `c#` has the same. so `t.triggerOn in (TriggerOn.CreateTionDelay, TriggerOn.CollisionDelay...)`

Comment: You can make a set or array out of it and call contains, but that would be a little much unless you use this group regularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to reduce the number of characters, you can use the indices of the enum-values. Example:

```
    if(t.triggerOn == 0 || t.triggerOn == 1 || t.triggerOn == 2 /* ... */)
    {
        // Do something
    }
```

where 0, 1, etc. must correspond to the indices of the TriggerOn values you want. The drawback to this is, it's hard to tell what conditions you're accepting just by looking at the line.

That said, you could also break your original code into multiple lines for readability.

```
    if(t.triggerOn == TriggerOn.CreationDelay ||
       t.triggerOn == TriggerOn.CollisionDelay ||
       t.triggerOn == TriggerOn.RigidbodyRestDelay ||
       t.triggerOn == TriggerOn.LayerCollisionDelay ||
       t.triggerOn == TriggerOn.EnterRadiusDelay)
    {
        // Do something
    }
```

I would suggest to keep your code as is (maybe break it into multiple lines), because understandability is readability.

*Understandability... Hmmm...*

Anyhow, I hope that helps!

Comment: I just broke the line into multiple lines like your example shows.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn It's what I would have done too. I'm glad I could help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I believe in this case for readability you may want to consider a switch statement.

```
switch (caseSwitch)
{
    case TriggerOn.CreationDelay:
        //do some stuff
        break;
    case TriggerOn.CollisionDelay:
        //do more stuff
        break;
    default:
        //do some more stuff
        break;
}
```

or with multiple case for one decision

```
switch (value)
{
   case TriggerOn.CreationDelay:
   case TriggerOn.CollisionDelay:
   case TriggerOn.RigidbodyRestDelay:
      //do some stuff
      break;
   case TriggerOn.LayerCollisionDelay:
   case TriggerOn.EnterRadiusDelay:
      //do more stuff
      break;
   default:
       //default stuff
      break;
}
```

Comment: Why would he need a switch statement if he only has 1 case?

Comment: For something that short, a switch just adds more noise, IMO.

Comment: I am just assuming there are more conditions after this one. If that's not the situation then this isn't a solution.

Comment: I would add that you can have multiple cases grouped together (eg `case TriggerOn.CreationDelay: case TriggerOn.CollisionDelay: case TriggerOn.LayerCollisionDelay:`) that all correspond to the same code.

Comment: Thank you Andrew Piliser for the useful information.

Comment: You should update your example and use the enums instead of int placeholders. You can just copy the enum values from the OP's question.

Comment: Thank you Scott Chamberlain, I believe I have adjusted it according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work... if you are checking all delays.

```
var _delaylist = TriggerOn.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Delay"));

if (_delaylist.Any(x => x.GetValue(x) == t.TriggerOn)
{
    //dowork
}
```

Comment: This would work but giving up readability for reducing a little bit of code is never good imo

Comment: That is true if this is the only statement. I have to agree with the synopsis of there is no great way to shorten it, but I aim to please and wanted to provide an answer that might be useful. One place I could see this sort of implementation being useful is if he needs to check any delay info outside of this block.

Answer (score 0):

I did create an `IN` method that you can search an enum, but it doesn't really save much space.

```
public static class Search<T> {
    public static bool IN(T val, params T[] items){
        foreach (T item in items) {
            if(val.Equals(item)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

It gets used like this:

```
if(Search<TriggerOn>.IN(t.triggerOn, TriggerOn.LayerCollision, TriggerOn.EnterRadius...)){
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the enum, then decorating with attributes can give nice readability and separate the metadata from your code.  For example:

```
public enum TriggerOn
{
    [DelayedTrigger]
    CreationDelay,

    NoCreation,

    [DelayedTrigger]
    CollisionDelay,

    CollisionStandard,

    [DelayedTrigger]
    RigidbodyRestDelay,

    [DelayedTrigger]
    LayerCollisionDelay,

    [DelayedTrigger]
    EnterRadiusDelay
}

public class DelayedTriggerAttribute : Attribute
{

}
```

You can then re-write your code to use a nice extension method which tests for the attribute, e.g.:

```
t.triggerOn.IsDelayedTrigger()
```